# Add last command's exit code to tmux *window* indicator in status line

Tags: tmux

I've got a tmux session that's got some ML models training in one window while I edit a markdown report in my current window. Every now and again the program that's training the models will fail and I'll need to restart them. But because they're in another window, the only way to know if they've failed is to go to that window every couple of minutes. This is annoying to say the least, and ineffective because I'm a bit forgetful.

I could have the models training in a pane in my current window, but lots of stuff gets printed to stdout and its distracting, which isn't what I need while I'm writing.

I know there's lots you can customise with tmux's status line [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/monitor-exit-code-in-tmux) [2](https://tao-of-tmux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manuscript/09-status-bar.html), but I haven't been able to figure this one out. I want to add a little icon to the end of each window that indicates if the most recently run command in that window's active pane ended in a non-zero exit code.

So for example, if my current statusline looks like:

```
[sess_name] 1:ml_training- 2:report_writing*
```

Then I want the ml_training window to update with a symbol if the running process fails with a non-zero exit code:

```
[sess_name] 1:ml_training-❗️ 2:report_writing*
```

This is similar to how, if you "zoom" a pane to make it take up the full window, you get a `Z` at the end of that pane's name:

```
[sess_name] 1:ml_training-Z 2:report_writing*
```

Is this possible? It needs to work even if I've got multiple panes in a window (in which case it should just pay attention to the active window). Weird edge cases like multi-pane input aren't important to worry about unless you want bonus points.

Comment: it'd be easier to use a simple script to restart your program on failure, like `while ! /your/ML/prog; do true; done`?

Comment: Sometimes it fails and needs me to give input / edit the code. So I'm more interested in monitoring the program as it runs in the background, and not so much auto-restarting it when it fails.

Comment: then dont use the loop, just update tmux status bar on failure.

Comment: I don't want to have to tweak every long-running command I will ever write. I don't want the command to send information to tmux, I want tmux to get information from the command (or more likely, from the shell which is running the command). Updating every command I run is error-prone and not a good solution.

Comment: usually there's a shell running in a tmux window/pane. based on my understanding tmux does not track status of the shell's sub-processes. you need to save shell's subprocess status somewhere and ask tmux to load from there and update its status bar accordingly.

Comment: tmux allows you to get the PID of a pane's process, and also lets you programmatically set the name of a window. So the unanswered question would be 1) can I get the exit code from a PID, and 2) can I add something to my .zshrc which updates tmux (if open) after each command has exited so that the exit code is reflected in the window name.

Posting these thoughts in case someone knows how to fill in the gaps

Comment: yes tmux has a `pane_pid` but its for "PID of **first** process in pane" which is usually the shell.